# Where exactly is defined this service into a Linux Ubunty 16.04 system?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-16.04

I am not so into Linux and I have the following problem. I am working on n **Ubuntu 16.04** system.

In this system I have a program that it is started from the command line in this way:

```
service wso2ei start
```

and stopped by:

```
service wso2ei stop
```

I think that somewhere it should be defined as a service or something like this. What exactly is this? And where is it defined these statment? (I think that is should be defined the association between the start command and the executable file that have to be executed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script defining the `start`, `stop`, `status`, ... actions of your service is defined in `/etc/systemd/system/wso2ei.service`.

Comment: This is Ubuntu 16.04 so isn’t it pre-systemd?

Comment: @Darren You ae right. In 16.04 it could be /etc/init.d/wso2ei